# Android: Set LiveData in ViewModel from a Service

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-service, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

The way I have my app set up is that, the **Service** will be getting some information in the background, which needs to be acquired live by the **Fragment**, and then display it into a view. To do this, **I put the data inside a ViewModel and let my Fragment observe the LiveData in the ViewModel.**

The problem is, I am having trouble **setting/changing the LiveData inside the ViewModel class from the service.** It seems that ViewModel is meant to be used between Activities and Fragments, and I cannot seem to get the ViewModel inside my service in order to change the value that needs to be observed by my Fragment. Is there a way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use a Repository with its own MutableLiveData field that is modified within your service. Your ViewModel will then have a MutableLiveData field that points to the Repository field, and your Fragment can observe that field.

Fragment:

```
...
viewModel.myData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { myData ->
    // handle new data observed
}
...
```

ViewModel:

```
// Need to clear repo reference in [onCleared] to avoid resource leaks
private var _myData: MutableLiveData<MyData>? = myRepo.myData
val myData: MutableLiveData<MyData> = _myData
...
override fun onCleared() {
    super.onCleared()
    _myData = null
}
```

Repository:

```
val myData = MutableLiveData<MyData>() // or whatever source (Room, etc.)
```

Service:

```
...
Repository.getInstance().myData.postValue(/* some new info */)
...
```